# Long term behavior of the solution of $u'=e^{-u}-u$

Tags: analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system

Consider the autonomous differential equation $$\left\{\begin{matrix}u'&=&e^{-u}-u&=:&f(u)\\u(0)&=&u_0&\in&\mathbb{R}\end{matrix}\right.$$ How can we analyze the *long term behavior*$^1$ of its solution $u$?

---

$^1\;$ i.e. $\displaystyle\lim_{t\to T_\max}u(t)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Phase diagram. Here is the graph of $f$:

$\qquad\qquad\qquad$[image]

And the (very simple) phase diagram associated to this graph:

$\qquad\qquad$[image]

> For every $u_0$ the limit $u_\infty$ exists and solves $f(u_\infty)=0$, hence $u_\infty=W(1)\approx.567$.

Comment: I've never heard about the *Lambert W function* before. Obviously, it's exactly defined to be the root of $ue^{-u}-u$. However, how can I use this information in $\lim_{t\to\infty}u(t)$?

Comment: The Lambert W function is irrelevant, apart from the exact numerical value of $u_\infty$. The qualitative behaviour of $t\mapsto u(t)$ follows from the phase diagram, as explained in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

One little picture says more than a long speech!

Figure below and see :http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LambertW-Function.html

$e^{-u}-u=0$  -->  $ u e^u = 1$  --> $u=W(1)$

[image]

Comment: I don't get it. Why is $\displaystyle\lim_{t\to\infty}u(t)=\text{root of }f(u)$?

Comment: Because if a limit exists, the function u(t) doesn't vary anymore at the limit. So, at the limit, du/dt=0 . Since exp(-u)-u = du/dt, hense exp(-u)-u=0.

Comment: I've updated my question. Let $y:[0,T_\max)\to\mathbb{R}$ denote the solution. How do we know that $T_\max=\infty$, i.e. that $y$ exists on $[0,\infty)$?